# SQL in MS Access max of sum

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, sum, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT  
    tableResults.PoliticalParty, 
    MAX(PoliticalPartyVotes.TotalVotes) AS [EX11]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         tableResults.PoliticalParty, 
         SUM(INT(tableResults.Votes)) AS TotalVotes
     FROM tableResults 
     GROUP BY tableResults.PoliticalParty) AS PoliticalPartyVotes;
```

This doesn't work, `tableResults.PoliticalParty` not showing one one result with max.

Comment: tag your database, such as SQL server, My SQL? and also your expected output in tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `PoliticalParty` with most votes, you can use `ORDER BY` and `TOP (1)` in your existing aggregate query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) PoliticalParty, Sum(INT(Votes)) AS TotalVotes
FROM tableResults 
GROUP BY tableResults.PoliticalParty
ORDER BY Sum(INT(Votes)) DESC
```

To allow top ties (ie, two `PoliticalParty` having the same, maximum total of votes), the  you can use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` instead.